# How to use MongoTemplate to update data in a simple way?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongotemplate

the mongo data like this:

```
    {
    "_id": ObjectId("616c1f02db88596cf8e141d5"),
    "kosList": [
        {
            "kosId": "279941070304",
            "name": "xxx",
            "fullPath": "KOS12"
        }
    ]
}
```

I can use js sql to update data, like this:

```
 db.collection.find(
{
    _id:ObjectId("616c1f02db88596cf8e141d5")
}
)

db.knowledge_resource_copy1.find(

{
kosList:{$elemMatch:{fullPath:{$regex:/KOS12/}}},

}

)

.forEach(
    function(item){
    item.kosList.forEach(
        function(kos){
                if(kos.fullPath.match(/KOS12/)){

                        kos.fullPath="testKos"+kos.fullPath.substr(0,7);

                }

            }

        );
            db.knowledge_resource_copy1.update(
                    {_id:item._id},
                    {$set:{"kosList":item.kosList}}
                    );
    }

);
```

I want to use MongoTemplate in java to achieve result of js sql , is there any way that just use update function and do not use find function to do this ?

Comment: You can try using [Array Update Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update-array/) to query and update the array element of the document as a single operation.